# Windows 10 keeps blue screening

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bsod

I have been getting a lot of blue screens recently with various errors such as "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA", "SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION"and "CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED_".

I have tried each RAM stick individually and both give the blue screen when used on their own. I have also tried a fresh install of Windows on a different hard drive. I removed the graphics card when installing Windows and did not put it back in yet it blue screened.

With the fresh install on a separate hard drive Windows booted fine after the blue screen, however on the old installation Windows fails to boot after a blue screen and requires a Windows repair multiple times to get back into Windows.

The only components I have not swapped out are the motherboard, CPU, PSU and peripherals.

Could one of these be causing the blue screen? If so is there a way I could test without purchasing replacement components?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a suggestion -- try running with one and then the other of the RAM sticks removed. When I was having repeated bluescreens with Windows 10, it turned out to be a bad ram stick.

Comment: When the machine crashes it creates dump files (*.dmp) and puts them in the windows directory.  go to https://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed  and download/install/run the program "who crashed". it will analyze your dump files and (hopefully) point you in the direction of the problem.

Comment: @Larryc The errors I get are: 
crash dump file: C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\041220-24406-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x1C2380) 
Bugcheck code: 0xEF (0xFFFFD40E7F3214C0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
and crash dump file: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP
This was probably caused by the following module: ntdll.sys (ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14) 
Bugcheck code: 0xEF (0xFFFFD40E7F3214C0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1. Attempt to repair Windows using [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness), since this seems to be an OS issue.

   - Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `cmd`, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and accept the UAC prompt to open the CMD prompt as Administrator.
   - Enter the following, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and *wait* some time for it to finish:

   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

   - Try [other Window repair techniques](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/repair-windows-10).
2. On the other hand, you might have hardware issues. Try running from a live flash USB drive *without* using the SSD or HDD to boot. For example, create a [live Ubuntu USB drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) and let it run for a few hours to see if it crashes. If it does, the issue is not with Windows OS, nor the SSD or HDD, but other hardware.

Comment: The first option worked for a couple of days but I just had a blue screen again. I'm pretty sure it's not the hardware as this worked flawlessly for Windows 7 which was installed at the same time as Windows 10.

Comment: I also tried running Ubuntu from a USB drive. I got to the desktop, heard a login noise but the screen remained black.